# parser: fs.readFile / createReadStream utf8 or hex

Tags: node.js, parsing, encoding

If I want to write a parser to interpret a custom language and want to read a stream of binary data to analyze a textfile (containing the source code) character by character, is there a benefit of using hex over utf8?

I have viewed some source code of existing parsers and they seem to prefer using hex to identify certain characters (e.g. tab, space etc), and even base64.

Is there a specific reason to do this?
Or perhaps a more useful question: why/when would you choose one over the other?